# Android no such column on variable name

Tags: android, sql

I am trying to do a simple select statement within my application. What I am trying to do is return a code that is associated to the word which is received from the list view. When I run the code I get an error saying the column doesnt exists. The column that it says doesnt exists is actually the variable I passing into the statement and not any of the columns in the table. Any help would be great

**SQL Statement**

```
//gets recipe code given recipe name
public Cursor getCode(String name) throws SQLException
{
    return db.rawQuery("select recipe_code from recipes where recipe_name = " + name ,null);
}
```

**Passing Variable to statement**

TextView txtProduct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recipeTitle);

```
    Intent i = getIntent();
    // getting attached intent data
    String string = i.getStringExtra("recipe");
    // displaying selected product name
    txtProduct.setText(string);

    adapter.open();

    Cursor code = adapter.getCode(string);
```

**Table Create**

```
//Recipe create statement
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_RECIPES = "CREATE TABLE "
        + RECIPE_TABLE + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER AUTO INCREMENT,"
        + KEY_CODE + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_RECIPE_NAME + " TEXT" + ")";
```

Comment: Where are you creating table in your code? Can you post that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use like this,

```
public Cursor getCode(String name) throws SQLException
{
    return db.rawQuery("select recipe_code from recipes where recipe_name = " + "'"+name+"'" ,null);
}
```

keep your variable within single quote.

Comment: Thanks, completely forgot about the single quotes

Comment: Just another question, if i want to use the value returned in the cursor in another statement, how do I extract the value into a variable?

Comment: @Hayes121 sorry for late reply you can use below link for reference [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298835/how-to-retrieve-data-from-sqlite-database-in-android-and-display-it-in-textview)