# How to fetch all inserted records in SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Hello Friends i want to fetch all records in sqlite and want to print it in Log.can anyone tell me how to do this in an android.below is my code.i dont want to display this records in array list or textview just want to print it in Logcat.i dont know what is role of getWritableDatabase and getredableDatabase.plz give some details of it.i am new in android.thanks in advanced.

```
public class DataBase {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "health";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Device_Data";

    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_Site_Id = "siteId";
    private static final String KEY_Patient_Id = "patientId";
    private static final String KEY_ReadingType = "readingType";
    private static final String KEY_DeviceMACId = "deviceMACId";
    private static final String KEY_DeviceData = "deviceData ";
    private static final String KEY_DeviceType = "deviceType";

    private final Context context;

    private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
    public SQLiteDatabase db;
    // private static final String TAG = "DataBase";

    static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + "TABLE_NAME" + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," + KEY_Site_Id + " TEXT ,"
            + KEY_Patient_Id + " TEXT ," + KEY_ReadingType + " TEXT ,"
            + KEY_DeviceMACId + " TEXT ," + KEY_DeviceData + " TEXT ,"
            + KEY_DeviceType + " TEXT ,")";

    public DataBase(Context _context) {
        context = _context;
        dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,
                DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "Device_Data");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    void addJson(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.getVersion();
        System.out.println("Database Version : " + db.getVersion());
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        try {
            values.put(KEY_Site_Id, json.getString("siteId"));

            values.put(KEY_Patient_Id, json.getString("patientId"));
            System.out.println("KEY_PATIENT_ID : "
                    + json.getString("patientId"));

            values.put(KEY_DeviceMACId, json.getString("deviceMACId"));
            System.out.println("KEY_DeviceMACId : "
                    + json.getString("deviceMACId"));

            values.put(KEY_ReadingType, json.getString("readingType"));
            System.out.println("KEY_ReadingType : "
                    + json.getString("readingType"));

            values.put(KEY_DeviceData, json.getString("deviceData"));
            System.out.println("KEY_DeviceData : "
                    + json.getString("deviceData"));

            values.put(KEY_DeviceType, json.getString("deviceType"));
            System.out.println("KEY_DeviceType : "
                    + json.getString("deviceType"));


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("JsonException........");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        long res = db.insert("Device_Data", null, values);
        System.out.println("Response Result : " + res);

        db.close();
    }

    public DataBase open() throws SQLException {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance() {
        return db;
    }
```

Comment: see this link.http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve data from sqlite database in android and display it in TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298835/how-to-retrieve-data-from-sqlite-database-in-android-and-display-it-in-textview)

Answer (score 1):

You can get all data from database..

```
// Getting All Contacts
public List<ReportTable> getAllReportDetail() {
    List<ReportTable> reportList = new ArrayList<ReportTable>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + yourTABLE_Name;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {


            ReportTable reportTable = new ReportTable();
            reportTable.set_ReportID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            reportTable.set_ReportPaymentMode(cursor.getString(1));
            reportTable.set_ReportRechargeMobileNo(cursor.getString(2));


            // Adding contact to list
            reportList.add(reportTable);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return reportList;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You call getWritableDatabase to make sure that your DB can read, write, update... bla bla..

And remember everytime you make an operation (update, delete, insert):

```
First: open
..do something.....
Finally: Close.
```

You can get all entry in the table by doing something like this:

```
public ArrayList<HealthData> getAllData() {
        ArrayList<HealthData> res = new ArrayList<HealthData>();

        Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, allNoteColumn, null, null, null, null, null);
        for(cursor.moveToLast(); !cursor.isBeforeFirst(); cursor.moveToPrevious()) {


            HealthData data = cursorToData(cursor);
            res.add(data);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return res;
    }


    private HealthData cursorToData(Cursor cursor) {
        HealthData data = new HealthData(
                cursor.getString(0),
                cursor.getString(1),
                cursor.getString(2),
                cursor.getString(3));
            // depending on how many column in your table, above is 4 column.
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: Just curious. Any reason why your Cursor goes backwards?

Comment: I'm create cursorToData method to make it reusable in some other case.

Comment: That shouldn't matter, should it? That method only looks at a single row. I meant the for loop.