# how retrive image and text from db to android togther

Tags: android, web-services

I want to retrieve image and string from table in my sql DB to display it in list view in android.

this is my php code:
[image: code]

I don't know how to retrieve image and text.

Comment: why  `PHP` when you tagged `android` for your question ?

Comment: which project ? you can't use `php` for developing android and if you point server side why you don't tell this in your question ? pls read `how to ask`   documentation of stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

If you want retrieve data from `server` to `android client`  you must use `Volley` library to load your `webservice` data and use [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/) .

But if you want retrieve data from `DB` stored in android device you must use android java class for DB see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298835/how-to-retrieve-data-from-sqlite-database-in-android-and-display-it-in-textview)

Comment: i used volley to rtive string data but i dont know how to rtrive all iamges and text together each elementt in row of list view