# Sqllite db retains earlier read values from JSON

Tags: android, sql

I am reading  a JSON file and putting it in my sqllite database using contentvalues and following code:
I have not added the JSON reading part as the file etc is being read fine. My problem is that :

**When I make changes in JSON file and rerun the application, I still get older values from db.**

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQuestion());
values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getAnswer());
values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOptA());
values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOptB());
values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOptC());
db.insert(TABLE_QUEST1, null, values);
```

Comment: show full work.

Comment: try with  `db.update` rather `insert`

Comment: If you just keep inserting values of course the old ones also remain. What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the table before adding new values or use replace function.

```
     db.dropAll();
```

> Drop all Method

```
  public void dropAll(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + advTABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + cliTABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + oppTABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + casTABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

get the values in list and then insert the values into DB again.

Comment: any other **random method names** ?

Answer (score 0):

Each run will create a new row. You need to read the correct row. An example of reading all rows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12299215/971170