# How do I read data from an SQLite database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

I am trying to read a row using a column name as key but I am somehow unable to get it.

Example I entered a string "name"

the list just shows "1" in the ListView

here's my insert code

```
public void insertStudent(String name, int faculty){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("name", name);
        cv.put("faculty", faculty);
        mSqliteDatabase.insert("students", null, cv);
    }
```

And here's how I query the data:

```
public List<String> selectAllEngg(){
        List<String> allStudents = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = mSqliteDatabase.query("students", new String[]{"faculty"}, null, null, null, null, null);
        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {

                allStudents.add(cursor.getString(0));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return allStudents;
    }
```

---

```
package test;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyDBAdapter {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";

    private Context mContext;
    private MyDBHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mSqliteDatabase;
    private int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public MyDBAdapter(Context context){
        this.mContext = context;
        mDbHelper = new MyDBHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public void open(){
        mSqliteDatabase = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public class MyDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
        public MyDBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version){
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
            String query = "CREATE TABLE students(id integer primary key autoincrement, name text, faculty integer);";
            db.execSQL(query);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
            String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS students;";
            db.execSQL(query);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public void insertStudent(String name, int faculty){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("name", name);
        cv.put("faculty", faculty);
        mSqliteDatabase.insert("students", null, cv);
    }

//    public List<String> selectAllStudents(){
//        List<String> allStudents = new ArrayList<>();
//        Cursor cursor = mSqliteDatabase.query("students", null, null, null, null, null, null);
//        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
//            do {
//                allStudents.add(cursor.getString(1));
//            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
//        }
//        return allStudents;
//    }

    public List<String> selectAllEngg(){
        List<String> allStudents = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cursor = mSqliteDatabase.query("students", new String[]{"faculty"}, null, null, null, null, null);
        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("faculty")).equals("1")){
                    allStudents.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
                }
//                allStudents.add(cursor.getString(0));

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return allStudents;
    }

    public void deleteAllEngineers(){
        mSqliteDatabase.delete("students", null, null);
    }
}
```

I added my DB java file please see it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve data from sqlite database in android and display it in TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298835/how-to-retrieve-data-from-sqlite-database-in-android-and-display-it-in-textview)

Answer (score 3):

using zero in cursor.getString(0) returns 1 as your query contains only one column "faculty" which is integer as per your table specification. But agree with Zoe that this is bad practice and leads to difficult to maintain and debug code.

in order to have a query with names and faculty you need to include both in the columns array string of your query, I recommend this way (more readable code):

```
String[] columns = {"name","faculty"};
Cursor cursor = mSqliteDatabase.query("students", columns, null, null, null, null, null);
```

or your way:

```
Cursor cursor = mSqliteDatabase.query("students", new String[]  {"name","faculty"}, null, null, null, null, null);
```

in this way you need to change the arraylist to  a map for example (collection that accept a key and a value) or implement your table columns as a class and use arraylist of that class type, or make your list of type string array like:

```
ArrayList<String[]> allStudents  = new ArrayList();
allStudents.add(new String[] {"put here faculty integer","put here student name"});
```

hope this may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Using `cursor.getString(0)` is (IMO) bad practice. That assumes you actually know the column index, and while you can find it fairly easily, it's better doing this:

```
allStudents.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
```

Preferably declaring the column name as a static constant though, but this still works assuming you write the name right.

The reason you're getting `"1"` as the output is most likely because the column at `0` doesn't point to the name column.

Comment: Okay this is how it works:

I have an EditText that a user inputs a name and I also have a spinner where they can choose a faculty(Engineering,Business, and Arts). There is a button where you save the infos to the DB

I'm trying to get a list of names per college

I can't seem to figure out how to? any ideas?