# Getting data from database and displaying it in a dialogue box

Tags: android, database, android-recyclerview, textview

I want to get data from database and display it in a text view in a dialog box. In my application, I have a button that when it is clicked, a dialogue box will open. there is a text view in this dialogue box. The text view is going show data from SQLite database. Let me say some more. My database has four fields. one is id, the second title, third is the body and the last one is the translation of the body in another language. In the activity that shows the body, I have a button that when the user clicks on it, a dialogue box will appear that displays the translation. I have used recyclerView to show the titles and bodies.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298835/how-to-retrieve-data-from-sqlite-database-in-android-and-display-it-in-textview

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is to use Room and MVVM [like this.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARpn-1FPNE4) The second option is to create a cursor and grab the data from that.

Comment: Thanks. I want to use a cursor. but how can I access textView in dialogue?

Comment: Getting the TextView is the easy part just use TextView text = findViewById(R.id.The Id of your text view); Then you can just use text.getText() or setText() to change the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME", null);
while(c.moveToNext()){
    int id = c.getInt(0);
    String title = c.getString(1);
    String body = c.getString(2);
    String bodyTranslated = c.getString(3);
}
```

This above code shows that the data is fetched from database and the cursor object is used to get the data and show it on the screen.

If you have problem with showing data in the AlertDialog check this link: [Custom Dialog + Sending Information to Activity - Android Studio Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARezg1D9Zd0)

For RecyclerView related issues check this link: [RecyclerView + CardView - Part 1 - LAYOUTS AND CUSTOM OBJECTS - Android Studio Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nw9JF55LDzE)