# Displaying 10 items at a time from mysql lite database in textview without using Base Adaptor Android Studio

Tags: android

As a beginner of Android Studio (java), I am using very basic coding techniques.  Is there anyway I can display in a TextView box, 10 items from a MySQL lite database, then click Next Button, and show 10 more and so on and so on.  The same concept for clicking a Previous Button but in reverse order, without using Base Adaptor? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12299215/5705721)

1. create the TextView and button
2. the assign data like this

   ```
   String[] stringArray = getTenItems();
   String finalString = "";
   for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
       finalString += stringArray[i];
   }
   myTextView.setText(finalString);
   ```